# Recovering a HD wallet from a partial seed phrase

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, python, mnemonic-seed, bip44

I am attempting to help recover a wallet where the owner only wrote down 11 of the 12 words in the seed phrase. Initially, I thought the task would be a quick and well-defined, but it appears to be a bit more complex than I assumed, and reference material is pretty scant. In the event that someone else has a similar issue to mine, I want to leave this post detailing the steps I followed (with working code samples).

The wallet I'm dealing with is Breadwallet, which apparently uses a different (older) mnemonic-to-HD-master-private-key derivation strategy from most modern wallets. For the moment, I'm only going to focus on recovering partial Breadwallet phrases, but I plan to eventually expand the answer to cover newer derivation strategies ([BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki)) as well.

Comment: This is really good stuff. How would it work if was using a 13 word Electrum (2.x) wallet, where only the first seed word was missing? So we have position, but additional variability of the differences in entropy etc. with 13 versus 12...

Comment: With one word missing, and a known position, regenerating the seed is easy. The checksum is built into the seed, so there's very few words that even have a possibility of working (likely only a handful of seeds you'd even need to try)

Comment: You should not be asking questions in an answers section.

Answer (score 6):

(The language used in this post is Python)

Breadwallet uses [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) to generate the 128-bit master seed from the 12-word mnemonic. The master seed is then used to generate a set of wallets/accounts containing chains of addresses, using [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki).

[image: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/raw/master/bip-0032/derivation.png]

---

First off, import hashlib and binascii, we're going to need them later.

```
import hashlib
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
```

Lets assume you have 11 of the 12 words in your seed phrase. For simplicity's sake, I'll use the first 11 words in the BIP39 wordlist:

```
partial_seed_phrase = [ 'abandon', 'ability', 'able', 'about', 'above', 'absent', 'absorb', 'abstract', 'absurd', 'abuse', 'access' ]
```

The wordlist contains 2048 entries, which gives each word 11 bits of entropy (2<sup>11</sup> = 2048). The 12 words have 12*11 = 132 bits of entropy in total. The HD master seed is 128 bits in length, and there's a 4-bit checksum attached to the end, which brings the total bits up to 132. So far so good.

If we assume that the `wordlist` is a 2048-element list (omitted due to space constraints), we can find the index (in decimal) of the elements in `partial_seed_phrase`:

```
mnemonic_in_decimal = map(wordlist.index, partial_seed_phrase)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Let's convert `mnemonic_in_decimal` into an array of 11-bit wide binary numbers.

```
mnemonic_in_binary = map('{0:011b}'.format, mnemonic_in_decimal)
# ['00000000000', '00000000001', '00000000010', '00000000011', '00000000100', '00000000101', '00000000110', '00000000111', '00000001000', '00000001001', '00000001010']
```

We know that a single word (11 bits) is missing from some unknown location in this array. In non-ideal circumstances, we would have to check each of the 12 locations for the missing word against 2048 possible words each, for a total of 24576 (12*2048 = 24576) potential master seeds.

```
for missing_word_position in range(0,12):
    # The missing word belongs at some index from 0-11 in the final 12-word phrase

    for wordlist_index in range(0, 2048):
        # Iterate over all possibilities for the missing word

        missing_word_binary = '{0:011b}'.format(wordlist_index)
        front_half          = ''.join(mnemonic_in_binary[0:missing_word_position])
        back_half           = ''.join(mnemonic_in_binary[missing_word_position:12])
        seed_and_checksum   = front_half + missing_word_binary + back_half

        seed     = seed_and_checksum[0:128]
        checksum = seed_and_checksum[-4:]
```

Thankfully, we have a 4-bit checksum, which means only one in every 16 seeds (2<sup>4</sup> = 16) will be valid. This means we will end up with a final total of approximately 1536 master seeds (24576/16 = 1536) to check for funds. The checksum is derived from the first bits (in this case, 4) returned by applying the SHA-256 hash function to the seed, so the final number of valid master seeds can vary, but will average out at around 1/16th of the total possible seeds.

[ More to come later, if anyone wants to help write descriptions or code for any of the following steps, I would appreciate it! ]

To do:

1. Calculate the actual_checksum from the first 4 bits of sha256(seed)
2. compare checksum to actual_checksum. If they are equal, push the seed into an array of valid master seeds.
3. Calculate the master node, which is HMAC-SHA512(seed)
4. Calculate an account from the master node
5. Calculate a wallet chain from the account
6. Calculate the first 5 private keys in the wallet chain
7. Calculate the first 5 public keys from those private keys
8. Write up a description and steps for recovering partial phrases for BIP44 wallets
9. Write a program to query either a blockchain locally, or a blockchain explorer API online. Pass it the combined list of generated public keys, and see if any have a balance.